# is bean development kit and netbeans IDE one and the same thing

Tags: java

I have a very old book Java 2 fourth edition by Herbert Schildt . There is a chapter Java Beans which requires Bean Development Kit to be downloaded from java.sun.com which is now owned by Oracle.However BDK is not available and only Netbeans IDE is available .The problem is I do not  know the difference between them.I wish to learn Java beans .So what do i need to learn ? 
I have Basic knowledge about java and its core APIs .I have started learning jsp and servlets and at this point i need to know Java Beans . 
I have googled and "stackoverflowed" it and still i have not found the answer.I hope this is not a dumb question .

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans is an [IDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment), which you can use to develop Java applications with beans. There are other alternatives available, you can search for those using Google.

More importantly, from what I can see your book is from **2001**. It is very likely that the information presented in that book is outdated, so I'd strongly suggest that you find a more recent book or try some online tutorials (again, a simple search on Google or SO should provide numerous options).
This brings me to the answer to your question: the development itself will be very similar, only the environment you'll work in is different.

Comment: what is the alternate of Bean Developer kit.Yes the book is outdated and so is bdk.I cant find the alternate of bdk even after googling for quite some time.Would you be kind enough to tell me its alternate

Comment: I'd say any IDE that supports Java, like Netbeans or Eclipse. Enter 'Java IDE' in Google and you'll get lots of results. I can't tell you which IDE is better, that is (in my opinion) a matter of opinion.